# I understand the meaning of the sentence. I just didn't get the final "な": 相変、人の話は聞かないな

Tags: negation

相変、人の話は聞かないな.

What's the purpose of the final な?

Comment: I'm more concerned by the "相変", which looks like it's missing approximately three okurigana...

Comment: hint: there's only one 「な」.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When is "na" used at the end of a sentence?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/33969/when-is-na-used-at-the-end-of-a-sentence)

Answer (score 1):

Sentence ending particle な indicates that what you're saying is an impression formed through your observation in the moment. If you reflect it into translation, "I see" or "after all" could work.

It usually changes into ね instead when you speak something to the listener in a more involving manner (otherwise it sounds a little too intimate).

When you are speaking to someone who is experiencing the same context in the moment, these な or ね can be translated like tag question depending on cases, which you may already know well. (In other words, it doesn't function as a tag question unless it fulfills the condition.)