# How is な used here?

Tags: grammar, negation, sentence-final-particles, imperatives, particle-な

> 鈴木よ、聞いてやるな。そちらの道には君の息子が気に入っている娘がいるのだ

Context: 鈴木 asks his son what was in that direction since his son was looking that direction. Then someone else said the above sentence.

I'm confused about the part 鈴木よ、聞いてやるな. It's especially confusing how the 'な ' is used here. Can anyone can help me?

Answer (score 5):

I think the な is the negative imperative meaning ***don't do***. So, the speaker is telling 鈴木 to not ask his son. The second sentence shows the speaker's reasoning with the explanatory のだ: because there's a girl 鈴木's son is interested in on that hill.

Here's another answer regarding this: [When is "na" used at the end of a sentence?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/33969/when-is-na-used-at-the-end-of-a-sentence)