# Understanding and grammar meaning behind "やったことないしなー"

Tags: grammar, translation, meaning

I'm reading a Japanese manga and I found this "maybe" slang sentence. A female character is asked to perform as actress in a school movie and her answer is:

> "えーー女優とか、やったことないしなー"

My guess is "An actress? I've never done it" but the grammar meaning looks obscure. Maybe I'm wrong but two negations arise: "ない" and "しなー." I think it's a contraction coming from "しない" or "しなかった". Probably some particles have been omitted too.

Answer (score 7):

しなー isn't a contracted negation.  Rather, you have the [sentence ending particle な](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/33969/when-is-na-used-at-the-end-of-a-sentence) preceded by し, which indicates a [partial list of reasons](http://www.guidetojapanese.org/learn/complete/multiple_verbs).

Given the usage of the particles my understanding is as follows:

> Whaaat?  But I haven't acted before (among other reasons).

Note that the な at the end of the sentence also indicates that she isn't super confident in her ability either.

Comment: If you want a more accurate translation from me, you will have to supply more context that leads up to the quote you have listed currently.

Comment: Many thanks! The sentence is related to an answer a manga character gives about a request to perform as an actress in a school movie.

Comment: @DomenicoFamularo Please edit your question to include more information.  Please include a couple lines of text from the manga ahead of the quotation of interest.  Specifically, the question that leads to the answer, as well as the answer in full.