usage of どこが int his context
ゆっくりでいいよな!
(どこがゆっくりでいいよな)
The characters are going out together and one tells the other: ゆっくりでいいよな! then as their date starts they get kinda chaotic and are very much into each other and the girl thinks this:
(どこがゆっくりでいいよな)
Is she wondering legit "where should I take it easy?" or is it making a comment how there is not place to take it easy?

It seems pretty similar to 何が〜 which is sort of a criticism of what someone said.

Does she really stop with よな, without any extra ～だ or ～よ and that kind?

どこ here doesn't literally mean "where" in the sense of a physical place/location. It refers to a part or aspect of something (def. 3 here; see also def. 5 for ところ and def. 2 for どこか on jisho). An easy example that instantly comes to mind is「彼のどこが好き？」"what about him do you like"?
So,「どこが～」means "what part of this is ～?"; "what about this is ～?"; "how is this ～?"; "～ how?". In this specific format (where どこが comes at the very front), the ～ part is often an exact quote of what someone said previously, and the question on the whole is sort of a refutation of that (as noted in the comments). You can look at examples from anime here.
(Can't offer an exact translation for your sentence specifically, because the な is throwing me off, and I'm getting skill-checked by the lack of full context.)

For this な, see https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/33969.

Oh, thanks for the ref, but it doesn't help sadly. I'm familiar with the particle in general, I just can't quite see how it fits here. (「ゆっくりでいいよ」on its own instantly makes sense to me as, like, permission-giving ["it's okay, you can take your time"], but the addition of な at the end invalidates that interpretation in my head, and replaces it with a range of possible "don't you think?"-type remarks, which I'm not quite sure what to make of... I think I need to see the scene in its entirety for it to properly click.)

Trying to translate these sentence-enders into specific English words is causing the hangup; just think about them in terms of the emotional effect they have. よね is a common combination, and it's pretty much the sum of its parts.

(let's move over to the chat room) https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/511/japanese-language
